# How to install emorf

Tags: emf, epsilon

I try to install emorf, i installed epsilon eclipse which contains different tools of modeling,But the the following error occurs,

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: EMorF Examples 0.4.2
>   (org.emorf.example.installer.feature.group 0.4.2)   Missing
>   requirement: EMorF Interpreter UI 0.4.1 (org.emorf.interpreter.ui
>   0.4.1) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.compare.match 1.2.1' but it could not be found   Missing requirement: EMorF Interpreter UI 0.4.2
>   (org.emorf.interpreter.ui 0.4.2) requires 'bundle
>   org.eclipse.emf.compare.match 1.2.1' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: EMorF Engine UI 0.4.1 (org.emorf.engine.ui.feature.group 0.4.1)
>       To: org.emorf.interpreter.ui [0.4.1]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: EMorF Engine UI 0.4.2 (org.emorf.engine.ui.feature.group 0.4.2)
>       To: org.emorf.interpreter.ui [0.4.2]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: EMorF Examples 0.4.2 (org.emorf.example.installer.feature.group 0.4.2)
>       To: org.emorf.sdk.feature.group 0.0.0   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: EMorF SDK 0.4.1 (org.emorf.sdk.feature.group 0.4.1)
>       To: org.emorf.engine.ui.feature.group [0.4.1]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: EMorF SDK 0.4.2 (org.emorf.sdk.feature.group 0.4.2)
>       To: org.emorf.engine.ui.feature.group [0.4.2]

It appears that the problem is that bundle org.eclipse.emf.compare.match 1.2.1 is missid but i don't know how to install it, can someone help me ?

Comment: On the install wizard page `Help > Install New Software...`, did you check `Contact all update sites during install to find required software` ?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem while trying to install it on Eclipse Mars. Apparently, only Indigo and Juno are supported, although the marketplace site states otherwise.

Just download an Eclipse Juno and install it there.